# Issues Getting User Screen Resolution

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm need to get the user Screen Resolution in my SharePoint site application page.

My first approach was using:

int ScreenHeight = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;

int ScreenWith = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;

but doing this in code behind the System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds doesn't get the correct values from user screen resolution.

In my research I found that using JavaScript is a better approach.

So I create my code like this:

In the application page I create the script:

var width = screen.width;
        var height = screen.height;

        if (width ').value = width;
        document.getElementById('').value = height;

The script is getting the values correctly because when I browse the page I can see the alert message with the correct screen resolution values.

The problem is that when I'm passing the values to code behind as in the code bellow I'm getting always the variables iScreenHeight and iScreenWith with null values:

string sScreenHeight = hScreenHeight.Value; 
string sScreenWith = hScreenWidth.Value;
int iScreenHeight = Convert.ToInt32(sScreenHeight);
int iScreenWith = Convert.ToInt32(sScreenWith);

if (iScreenHeight >= 1280 && iScreenWith >= 1024)
            {
                lblScreenResolution.Text = "Resolution" + "=" + iScreenHeight + "x" + iScreenWith;
                lblScreenResolution.ForeColor = Color.Green;

```
        }
        else {
            lblScreenResolution.Text = "Resolution" + "=" + iScreenHeight + "x" + iScreenWith;
            lblScreenResolution.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
```

I think I'm passing correctly the values to the HidenField but I don't know why I'm getting the variables = null when the page loads.

Can any one help me in this code or give me a better approach is exist, I already google it a lot but nothing seems to work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with native JavaScript by pulling from the [screen object](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml). screen.width & screen.height will give you the width and height, respectively.

If you've got jQuery loaded, you can also use $(window).height() and $(window).width() for the same thing, but this is one of those cases where simple core JavaScript makes more sense unless you already have jQuery loaded. jQuery will do some cross-browser compatibility to make sure you're getting accurate readings across all browsers, whereas the core JavaScript approach will sometimes be inconsistent.

That said, if all you're trying to do is do some rudimentary resolution detection, the core stuff *should* be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for you help, but I have one question? After get the screen.width and screen.height how I pass the value to the code behind to out my logic? I tried using HidenFields but the values are always null. Can you give me a code example? Thank You

Comment: You have to store it in a cookie or pass it via ajax once read, or store into a hidden input somewhere for post requests etc.

Comment: The approach from @HughWood above would work. You can't simply pass from front-end to back-end because the code behind executes pre-render and the JavaScript executes post-render. That's the core difference between server side and client side. You can write from server side to the client, but not from the client to the server. You'd have to capture/store then do a post back to load it (using one of those methods). What are you trying to do? I'd imagine there's a better way than this.

Comment: I think you get the point "webdes03", but can you give me one example how I do a postback to load it is asp.net without the use of one button?

Comment: I would use $("document").ready(function() {...}); and in there call an ajax function which performs a get request to a custom handler that stores it in the location you require. If you need the information for the page you are looking at then the ONLY reason I forsee you needing it can be manipulated in real time with jquery/javascript. With these two methods you can either do an automated post back or cut out the need for one at all.

Comment: I would agree with Hugh's approach. You could also potentially use your code behind to write out the script that gets and sets the values of your fields. I'm still curious as to why your code behind needs to know the screen width/height. If you can give us more background on what you're trying to accomplish we can probably better advise.

Comment: Yes sure, Basically I'm creating a application page to do some PC/browser verification, I'm validating the IE, Javascript enable, cookies enable and user Screen Resolution. I have some labels in the page where fill with the values/text I want (IE version, Javascript enable, etc). Thinking on this probably I can bind/set the label.text value in javascript, but how that is done?

Comment: So my first question would be if there's a specific need for this to be a code behind? Are you doing something with the information, or are you simply alerting the user if they don't meet the required configuration? You can easily accomplish all of this in straight JavaScript and disable or mask the form/content so they can't see/use it if they don't meet the specs. Browser type/version, resolution, etc. is all available to native JavaScript. It just seems like you're making things harder than they have to be (unless I'm missing something). If you're checking client-side, leave it client-side.

Comment: I yes you right, I don't need code behind, but I'm not a experienced frontend/javascript developer.How do I set the label.text = javascript variable, I'm using this but is not working: var height = screen.height;  var testlabel = '<%=lblScreenResolution.ClientID %>'; document.getElementById(testlabel).value = height;

Comment: If you do it client-side, you're not limited to using a "label" you can just create a div and an id ie: `<div id="StatusDiv"></div>` and write to it with JavaScript `var StatusDivContainer = document.getElementById("StatusDiv"); StatusDivContainer.innerHTML = "Message to the user";` if you have jQuery, that's all simplified to `$("#StatusDiv").html('Message to the user');`

Comment: So writing the height (as an example) could be as easy as `var StatusDivContainer.innerHTML = "Your height is " + screen.height + "and a minimum of xxxxx is required";`

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help, It's working..